# Can not get token for TextToSpeechAPI

Tags: azure

Here is the code:

```
private AccessTokenInfo GetToken()
{
     WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://oxford-speech.cloudapp.net/token/issueToken");
     webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     webRequest.Method = "POST";

     byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_requestDetails);
     webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

     try
     {
        using (Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        // ...
```

I have got the exception:

> the underlying connection was closed could not establish trust relationship

How can I fit it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm not missing something here...

The URL you're using isn't the one that generates tokens for the Text-to-Speech API as [documented here](https://msou.co/bgf). (The "Oxford" that's referenced in your URL refers to the Project Oxford which Cognitive Services was formerly known as.)

Also, `WebRequest` is deprecated. Use the `System.Net.Http` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) instead.

The code to invoke the new REST endpoint then would look something like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken"))
{
    request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "YOUR-KEY-HERE");
    var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
    var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Finally, there are several [client libraries](https://msou.co/bgg) that may get you around from writing any code to hit the REST services at all.